# Mobile not listed in adb devices only in my laptop

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

My Samsung J2 mobile is not getting listed in adb devices only on my Dell laptop.[adb devices result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnA2N.png)
Because of this Enable USB debugging screen [Enable USB debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZdRB.png) in not popping up

Things i have tried

1. Enabled developer options and USB debugging( Tried re enable after disabled also)
2. Restarted mobile and laptop
3. Deleted .android
4. Tried changing MTP to PTP
5. Factory reset my mobile and then enable Developer options and USB debug
6. Tried using more than one USB cables

**Important Note** : This issue is in my laptop only. In other machines its working fine. So i guess , problem is not in mobile

Comment: try to install Universal ADB installer to your laptop http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sathish Kumar. After opening the Universal ADB installer exe file, It stated that installed samsung driver was corrupted. After this i installed driver from Universal ADB. Worked Perfect!

Comment: welcome kindly mark as answer as mine. so others can easily find correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Install `Universal ADB installer` to your laptop [adbdriver.com/downloads](http://adbdriver.com/downloads)

there also having `Samsung official Android USB Driver`

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur due to ADB driver is not installed on your machine.
Install pdanet+ software for ADB drivers and it will help definitely.
[Click here](http://pdanet.co/a/)